# C# sql select and update if curRow

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Hi so I am having trouble with using the select statement to read from another database MAS4.4 is the program and updating it on sql server.  My code works its just once I tried updating with Convert.ToString i get errors and im not sure why.

Here is my code..

The Book is giving me the problem on Convert.ToString

```
    private delegate void AddPrimaryIndexHandler(System.Data.DataTable webData);
    private delegate System.Data.DataRow FindRowByIndexHandler(System.Data.DataTable webData, string partNumber);
    private int UpdateWeb(string sConnString, string sTableName, string sPrimaryColModifier, AddPrimaryIndexHandler addPrimaryIndexColumn, FindRowByIndexHandler findRowByIndex)
    {
        int updateCount = 0;
        using (OdbcConnection masConn = new OdbcConnection(masConnString))
        {
            masConn.Open();

            string masSelect = @"SELECT CI_Item.ItemCode, CI_Item.UDF_ROHS, CI_Item.UDF_CONFLICT_MINERALS, CI_Item.UDF_REACH138, CI_Item.UDF_CUSTOMER_LEAD_TIME, IM_ItemWarehouse.QuantityOnHand, IM_ItemWarehouse.QuantityOnSalesOrder, IM_ItemWarehouse.QuantityOnBackOrder, CI_Item.Category1
            FROM CI_Item, IM_ItemWarehouse 
            WHERE (CI_Item.ItemCode = IM_ItemWarehouse.ItemCode) AND (CI_Item.EBMEnabled = 'Y') AND (IM_ItemWarehouse.WarehouseCode = '001')";

            using (OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(masSelect, masConn))
            using (OdbcDataReader masReader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (masReader.HasRows)
                {
                    string webSelect = String.Format("SELECT {1}PartNumber, RohsCompliant, ConflictMinerals, Reach138Compliant, QtyOnHand, QtyOnSalesOrder, QtyOnBackOrder, UpdateDate, ReviewedBy, LEAD_TIME_WEEKS FROM, Book {0} WHERE WebEnabled = 'Y' AND RohsCompliant is not null and ConflictMinerals is not null and Reach138Compliant is not null", sTableName, sPrimaryColModifier);

                    using (SqlDataAdapter webAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(webSelect, sConnString))
                    using (SqlCommandBuilder commmandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(webAdapter))
                    {
                        webAdapter.UpdateBatchSize = 0;
                        commmandBuilder.ConflictOption = ConflictOption.OverwriteChanges;
                        DataTable webData = new DataTable("WebData");
                        webAdapter.Fill(webData);
                        addPrimaryIndexColumn(webData);

                        while (masReader.Read())
                        {
                            string partNumber = (string)masReader["ItemCode"];                                
                            string Rohs_Compliant = (string)masReader["UDF_ROHS"];
                            string Conflict_Minerals = (string)masReader["UDF_CONFLICT_MINERALS"];
                            string Reach138_Comliant = (string)masReader["UDF_REACH138"];
                            decimal qtyOnHand = (decimal)masReader["QuantityOnHand"];
                            decimal qtyOnSalesOrder = (decimal)masReader["QuantityOnSalesOrder"];
                            decimal qtyOnBackOrder = (decimal)masReader["QuantityOnBackOrder"];
                            decimal LEAD_TIME_WEEKS = (decimal)masReader["UDF_CUSTOMER_LEAD_TIME"];
                            string Book = (string)masReader["Category1"];   

                            DataRow curRow = findRowByIndex(webData, partNumber);
                            if (curRow != null)
                            {                    
                                bool needsUpdate = false;

                                if (Rohs_Compliant == "Y")
                                {
                                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(curRow["RohsCompliant"]) == false)
                                    {
                                        curRow["RohsCompliant"] = 1;
                                        needsUpdate = true;
                                    }
                                }

                                if (Rohs_Compliant == "N")
                                {
                                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(curRow["RohsCompliant"]) == true)
                                    {
                                        curRow["RohsCompliant"] = 0;
                                        needsUpdate = true;
                                    }
                                }

                                if (Conflict_Minerals == "Y")
                                {
                                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(curRow["ConflictMinerals"]) == false)
                                    {
                                        curRow["ConflictMinerals"] = 1;
                                        needsUpdate = true;
                                    }
                                }

                                if (Conflict_Minerals == "N")
                                {
                                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(curRow["ConflictMinerals"]) == true)
                                    {
                                        curRow["ConflictMinerals"] = 0;
                                        needsUpdate = true;
                                    }
                                }

                                if (Reach138_Comliant == "Y")
                                {
                                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(curRow["Reach138Compliant"]) == false)
                                    {
                                        curRow["Reach138Compliant"] = 1;
                                        needsUpdate = true;
                                    }
                                }

                                if (Reach138_Comliant == "N")
                                {
                                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(curRow["Reach138Compliant"]) == true)
                                    {
                                        curRow["Reach138Compliant"] = 0;
                                        needsUpdate = true;
                                    }
                                }

                                if (curRow["QtyOnHand"] is DBNull || Convert.ToDecimal(curRow["QtyOnHand"]) != qtyOnHand)
                                {
                                    curRow["QtyOnHand"] = qtyOnHand;
                                    needsUpdate = true;
                                }

                                if (curRow["QtyOnSalesOrder"] is DBNull || Convert.ToDecimal(curRow["QtyOnSalesOrder"]) != qtyOnSalesOrder)
                                {
                                    curRow["QtyOnSalesOrder"] = qtyOnSalesOrder;
                                    needsUpdate = true;
                                }
                                //
                                if (curRow["QtyOnBackOrder"] is DBNull || Convert.ToDecimal(curRow["QtyOnBackOrder"]) != qtyOnBackOrder)
                                {
                                    curRow["QtyOnBackOrder"] = qtyOnBackOrder;
                                    needsUpdate = true;
                                }

                                    //
                                if (curRow["LEAD_TIME_WEEKS"] is DBNull || Convert.ToDecimal(curRow["LEAD_TIME_WEEKS"]) != LEAD_TIME_WEEKS)
                                {
                                    curRow["LEAD_TIME_WEEKS"] = LEAD_TIME_WEEKS;
                                    needsUpdate = true;
                                }

                                //
                                if (curRow["Book"] is DBNull || Convert.ToString(curRow["Book"]) != Book)
                                {
                                    curRow["Book"] = Book;
                                    needsUpdate = true;
                                }

                                if (needsUpdate)
                                {
                                    curRow["UpdateDate"] = DateTime.Now;
                                    curRow["ReviewedBy"] = "Spider2.2";
                                }

                            }
                        }

                        updateCount = webAdapter.Update(webData);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return updateCount;
    }
}
```

}

Error Message:

```
2/6/2014 3:16:29 PM
Attempt 1: Error updating new database (DNN7) - Line: 0 Incorrect syntax near '.'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
   at Spider.Spider.UpdateWeb(String sConnString, String sTableName, String sPrimaryColModifier, AddPrimaryIndexHandler addPrimaryIndexColumn, FindRowByIndexHandler findRowByIndex)
   at Spider.Spider.RunWebUpdate(SpiderLog log, Int32 numberOfAttempts)
-1 DNN7 Part Numbers successfully updated.
Error updating old database (DNN6) - Line: 0 Invalid column name 'WebEnabled'.
Invalid column name 'RohsCompliant'.
Invalid column name 'ConflictMinerals'.
Invalid column name 'Reach138Compliant'.
Invalid column name 'PartNumber'.
Invalid column name 'RohsCompliant'.
Invalid column name 'ConflictMinerals'.
Invalid column name 'Reach138Compliant'.
Invalid column name 'QtyOnHand'.
Invalid column name 'QtyOnSalesOrder'.
Invalid column name 'QtyOnBackOrder'.
Invalid column name 'UpdateDate'.
Invalid column name 'ReviewedBy'.
Invalid column name 'LEAD_TIME_WEEKS'.
Invalid column name 'Book'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
   at Spider.Spider.UpdateWeb(String sConnString, String sTableName, String sPrimaryColModifier, AddPrimaryIndexHandler addPrimaryIndexColumn, FindRowByIndexHandler findRowByIndex)
   at Spider.Spider.RunWebUpdate(SpiderLog log, Int32 numberOfAttempts)
-1 DNN6 Part Numbers successfully updated.
Attempt 2: Error updating new database (DNN7) - Line: 0 Incorrect syntax near '.'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
   at Spider.Spider.UpdateWeb(String sConnString, String sTableName, String sPrimaryColModifier, AddPrimaryIndexHandler addPrimaryIndexColumn, FindRowByIndexHandler findRowByIndex)
   at Spider.Spider.RunWebUpdate(SpiderLog log, Int32 numberOfAttempts)
-1 DNN7 Part Numbers successfully updated.
Error updating old database (DNN6) - Line: 0 Invalid column name 'WebEnabled'.
Invalid column name 'RohsCompliant'.
Invalid column name 'ConflictMinerals'.
Invalid column name 'Reach138Compliant'.
Invalid column name 'PartNumber'.
Invalid column name 'RohsCompliant'.
Invalid column name 'ConflictMinerals'.
Invalid column name 'Reach138Compliant'.
Invalid column name 'QtyOnHand'.
Invalid column name 'QtyOnSalesOrder'.
Invalid column name 'QtyOnBackOrder'.
Invalid column name 'UpdateDate'.
Invalid column name 'ReviewedBy'.
Invalid column name 'LEAD_TIME_WEEKS'.
Invalid column name 'Book'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
   at Spider.Spider.UpdateWeb(String sConnString, String sTableName, String sPrimaryColModifier, AddPrimaryIndexHandler addPrimaryIndexColumn, FindRowByIndexHandler findRowByIndex)
   at Spider.Spider.RunWebUpdate(SpiderLog log, Int32 numberOfAttempts)
-1 DNN6 Part Numbers successfully updated.
Attempt 3: Error updating new database (DNN7) - Line: 0 Incorrect syntax near '.'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
   at Spider.Spider.UpdateWeb(String sConnString, String sTableName, String sPrimaryColModifier, AddPrimaryIndexHandler addPrimaryIndexColumn, FindRowByIndexHandler findRowByIndex)
   at Spider.Spider.RunWebUpdate(SpiderLog log, Int32 numberOfAttempts)
-1 DNN7 Part Numbers successfully updated.
Error updating old database (DNN6) - Line: 0 Invalid column name 'WebEnabled'.
Invalid column name 'RohsCompliant'.
Invalid column name 'ConflictMinerals'.
Invalid column name 'Reach138Compliant'.
Invalid column name 'PartNumber'.
Invalid column name 'RohsCompliant'.
Invalid column name 'ConflictMinerals'.
Invalid column name 'Reach138Compliant'.
Invalid column name 'QtyOnHand'.
Invalid column name 'QtyOnSalesOrder'.
Invalid column name 'QtyOnBackOrder'.
Invalid column name 'UpdateDate'.
Invalid column name 'ReviewedBy'.
Invalid column name 'LEAD_TIME_WEEKS'.
Invalid column name 'Book'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
   at Spider.Spider.UpdateWeb(String sConnString, String sTableName, String sPrimaryColModifier, AddPrimaryIndexHandler addPrimaryIndexColumn, FindRowByIndexHandler findRowByIndex)
   at Spider.Spider.RunWebUpdate(SpiderLog log, Int32 numberOfAttempts)
-1 DNN6 Part Numbers successfully updated.
```

Could this be the error?

```
   string masSelect = @"SELECT CI_Item.ItemCode, CI_Item.UDF_ROHS, CI_Item.UDF_CONFLICT_MINERALS, CI_Item.UDF_REACH138, CI_Item.UDF_CUSTOMER_LEAD_TIME, IM_ItemWarehouse.QuantityOnHand, IM_ItemWarehouse.QuantityOnSalesOrder, IM_ItemWarehouse.QuantityOnBackOrder, CI_Item.Category1
                FROM CI_Item, IM_ItemWarehouse 
                WHERE (CI_Item.ItemCode = IM_ItemWarehouse.ItemCode) AND (CI_Item.EBMEnabled = 'Y') AND (IM_ItemWarehouse.WarehouseCode = '001')";
```

I have CI_Item.Category1 at the end of the select statement ?

Comment: Its not that its not compiling its not updating the row ill post the error message hold on..

Comment: You have a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

It says this:

```
 Line: 0 Invalid column name 'WebEnabled'.
 Error updating old database (DNN6) - Line: 0 Invalid column name 'WebEnabled'.
 Invalid column name 'RohsCompliant'.
 Invalid column name 'ConflictMinerals'.
 Invalid column name 'Reach138Compliant'.
 Invalid column name 'PartNumber'.
 Invalid column name 'RohsCompliant'.
 Invalid column name 'ConflictMinerals'.
 Invalid column name 'Reach138Compliant'.
 Invalid column name 'QtyOnHand'.
 Invalid column name 'QtyOnSalesOrder'.
 Invalid column name 'QtyOnBackOrder'.
 Invalid column name 'UpdateDate'.
```

Comment: Could this be the error?

       string masSelect = @"SELECT CI_Item.ItemCode, CI_Item.UDF_ROHS, CI_Item.UDF_CONFLICT_MINERALS, CI_Item.UDF_REACH138, CI_Item.UDF_CUSTOMER_LEAD_TIME, IM_ItemWarehouse.QuantityOnHand, IM_ItemWarehouse.QuantityOnSalesOrder, IM_ItemWarehouse.QuantityOnBackOrder, CI_Item.Category1
                    FROM CI_Item, IM_ItemWarehouse 
                    WHERE (CI_Item.ItemCode = IM_ItemWarehouse.ItemCode) AND (CI_Item.EBMEnabled = 'Y') AND (IM_ItemWarehouse.WarehouseCode = '001')";


I have CI_Item.Category1 at the end of the select statement ?

Comment: you should run in debug, get the sql and run it to make sure it is valid.